# "User CN={user's name}/O={organisation name } cannot open database {path to databasename.nsf}"

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am getting this error when i am trying to access mail file(mail/usermail.nsf) of user ( on different machine) using C#.

I am using "Interop.Domino.dll".

Is this happening because of same user name and organization name?

But i am able to access local User NSF file (user configured on same machine where Domino server installed) where lotus notes client name is same as that of domain name.

Comment: Did you mean `Interop.Domino.dll`?

Comment: You seem to have confused the Organization (O) in the username with the server name - or are you sure they are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check would be:

- Are you opening the database using a server name and path (not just a mapped, remote file path)?
- Does the ID file being used have access to the server (in Server document in NAB, as mentioned by another response)?
- Does the ID file have access to the NSF (from a Notes client, use the "Effective Access" tool, from within the ACL dialog to verify)?
- If the file path you're using have the correct delimitters - you should be using a backslah () in your GetDatabase method call.
- Are you able to access and read content from any other NSF on the remote server? For example, a simple test would be to have your code open names.nsf in the root data folder.
- Finally, is it possible for you to post a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user has access to that mail file?  Also make sure the user ID has access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the file using the Notes client and that ID?  If not, your code won't be able to either.  In that case, check the "Who may access Server" section in the server document in the NAB and/or the Access Control List of the database, depending on the message you get on failing to access.